# Is this property call expensive

Tags: php

I'm using `isset()` to check for `$this->statarr['stat1']['stat2'][$var1])`. I included only 2 but I have many more.

```
if (isset($this->statarr['stat1']['stat2'][$var1])) {
   $value .= 'var 1: ' . $this->statarr['stat1']['stat2'][$var1];
}
if (isset($this->statarr['stat1']['stat2'][$var2])) {
   $value .= 'var 2: ' . $this->statarr['stat1']['stat2'][$var2];
}
...
```

Is it expensive to call the `$this->statarr` property that many times (10 or more)? Should I call `$this->statarr['stat1']['stat2']` once and store it in `$statarr`, then make the other checks, or it makes no difference in terms of efficiency?

```
$statarr = $this->statarr['stat1']['stat2'];

if (isset($statarr[$var1])) {
   $value .= 'var 1: ' . $statarr[$var1];
}
if (isset($statarr[$var2])) {
   $value .= 'var 2: ' . $statarr[$var2];
}
...
```

The other thing is how do I make sure that `$this->statarr['stat1']['stat2']` itself is set?

Comment: even 'if' it wasn't more efficient, which is more readable?

Comment: @Mitch, I know it's more readable, but I want to know if it's more efficient. I don't want to say that it's more efficient when it's not.

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about your code's efficiency, you can profile it using a profiling tool like Xdebug, http://xdebug.org/

Answer (score 2):

You may use xdebug to check for performance. In general these are not "big" deal breakers in my experience. File and database operations tend to be much more expensive.

Personally I would normalize it a bit like this (for readability and maintainability):

```
function conditionaljoin($array,$keys)
{
   $result = "";
   foreach ($keys as $key)
      if (isset($array[$key])
      {
          $result .= $array[$key]
      }
      return $result;
 }

 if (isset($this->['stat1']['stat2'])
     $value = conditionaljoin($this->['stat1']['stat2'], array($var1, $var2);
 }
```